# Duplicate input value in japanese keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a case like this:

Enter 1 zipcode with 7 characters.
for example: 1234567 will convert to 123-4567.
I've been able to handle it.

But there is a bug related to the Japanese keyboard on the phone.
That is, when inputting the input, the value it duplicates cannot control the value.

Here is the demo code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-https-h88nnx?file=/src/App.js:226-1853

Has anyone come across a case like this. And what keyword should I fix or search to solve?

```
export const REGEX_ONLY_NUMBER = /^[0-9]+$/;
export const INDEX_SEPARATE_ZIP_CODE = 4;

export default function App() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  const handleZipCodeChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value.replaceAll("-", "");

    // check input is number
    const isNumber = REGEX_ONLY_NUMBER.test(value);

    // add "-" after 3rd character
    if (value.length > INDEX_SEPARATE_ZIP_CODE - 1) {
      value = value.slice(0, 3) + "-" + value.slice(3);
    }

    // Store cursor position before assigning new value
    const previousCursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart || 0;

    // input only number
    e.target.value = !isNumber ? "" : value;
    form.setFieldValue("zipCode", e.target.value);

    // Restore cursor position after assigning new value
    if (previousCursorPosition < INDEX_SEPARATE_ZIP_CODE) {
      const newCursorPosition = Math.min(previousCursorPosition, value.length);
      e.target.setSelectionRange(newCursorPosition, newCursorPosition);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ maxWidth: "500px", margin: "100px auto" }}>
      <Form layout="vertical" form={form} onFinish={onFinish}>
        <Form.Item
          name="zipCode"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your zipcode!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            className={classNames({
              inputDefault: true
            })}
            maxLength={8}
            onChange={handleZipCodeChange}
            placeholder={"Nhập zipcode"}
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```